# Irreducible Polynomials and ring of integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I came across an exercise in a book which I do not how to solve.
Let $f(x) = x^5 -80x -2.$ Let $\alpha$ be a zero of this polynomial. Furthermore let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field. These are the questions that are asked:

1- Is this polynomial irreducible and why?
2- Find an integer $n$ such that $f(n) = 1.$
3- Show that $\alpha - n \in \mathcal O_K$

For part 1, For prime $p = 2$ we observe that $p$ does not divide the coefficient of the leading term but divides the other coefficients namely $-80, -2.$ Also $p^2 = 4$ does not divide $2.$ Therefore $f(x)$ by Eisenstein Irreducibility Criterion, is irreducible. Is this correct?

I am formally trained as a mechanical engineer and during this lockdown I am teching myself algebraic number theory. Please kindly provide as much details as possible as I am a bit clueless. Many thanks.

Comment: What are you reading and what is your background in abstract algebra?  You don't indicate why you decided to teach yourself algebraic number theory, but without some knowledge of abstract algebra it is going to be hard to read many books on algebraic number theory, as most assume familiarity with groups, rings, ideals, and homomorphisms.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please share your thoughts and efforts on the problem, so that others here can better help you. What methods for checking irreducibility have you tried? What is your background in abstract algebra? What is your definition of $\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: What is $p(n)$? I too am studying algebraic number theory. Also, what is $\mathcal O_K$ in this case? Is it a $K$-module?

Comment: I found abstract algebra, in particular group theory, interesting. That is why I started to study group theory, and algebraic number theory and hopefully move to galois theory soon. Of course this is very informal journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution to 1) is correct.  For 2), I can promise you that you will solve it with a few minutes of experimentation.  Try things!

For 3), I think you have omitted the important piece of information that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$!  Furthermore, the question as stated is trivial: $\alpha$ is the root of a monic integer polynomial, so it's an algebraic integer, and a regular integer $n$ is certainly an algebraic integer, and your book should have a proof that the sum of two algebraic integers is an algebraic integer.

I think the original problem was actually to show that $\alpha - n \in\mathcal{O}_K^\times$, i.e. that $\alpha-n$ is an algebraic integer whose inverse is also an algebraic integer.

My hint for showing this is to consider the following ratio: $$\frac{f(\alpha)-f(n)}{\alpha-n}$$

You will need the following fact, which holds for any integer polynomial $f$: $$\frac{f(X)-f(Y)}{X-Y}\in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$$

(to see this, look at each term of $f$)

Comment: Thank you Slade. For part two of the question, I found out $x=3$ satisfies the requirement

Comment: However, does this mean that $x-3$ is a factor of this polynomial and that fact makes $x^5 - 80x -2$ reducible rather than irreducible by reminder theorem?

Comment: @KASH80 No, if $x-3$ were a factor of $f$, then $f(3)$ would equal $0$.  But we've just established that $f(3)=1$.

Comment: What the fact I quoted tells us is that $f(x)-1$ is divisible by $x-3$.

Comment: of course! thanks for your help @Slade